# Is it possible to configure `.devcontainer` settings globally?

Tags: vscode-remote

My development workflow uses one docker container spun up through Docker Compose for all projects.

To the best I can tell the `Remote - Container` Extension only allows a configuration file to be created per project.

Having the ability to setup the extension either through a global `devcontainer.json` or in the `User` settings would be ideal so that:

1. It can use a `docker-compose.yml` file external to the project files when attaching to a running container
2. A user other than `root` can be set when attaching to the container through the extension
3. Take advantage that Docker Compose allows you to attach using the container `name` instead of `id`, as I rebuild the containers often which causes previous workspaces to fail when attempting to reconnect to the remote.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I've read through the documentation and also went to the user settings to look through the autocomplete of options. I kind of assumed since `devcontainer.json` is similar in nature to `launch.json` it too could be set in `User` settings, but it was not an available option like `"launch"` is.